# sforce.connection.query AccountId is Undefined

Tags: visualforce, javascript, sforce

I am getting AccountId as "Undefined" for some reason in sforce.connection.query.

```
try{ 

        var cons = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name,Accountid,Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id = '" + recordId + "'");

        var stats= cons.getArray("records");
        url +='&CF00N50000001oGFn='+stats[0].Name;
        url +='&CF00N50000001oGFd='+stats[0].Account.Name;
        url +='&CF00N50000001oGFd_lkid='+stats[0].Accountid;
        url +='&opp4='+stats[0].Account.Name;
        url +='&opp4_lkid='+stats[0].Accountid;

     var defaultValues = {
        'Name' : 'DV '+"-"+ today.getFullYear() + "-" + monthDigit + "-" + today.getDate(), 
        'AccountId':stats[0].Accountid,  
        'Donor_Account__c':stats[0].Accountid,  
        'Donor_Contact__c':stats[0].Id,  
        'retURL':'/006',
        'nooverride':'1'
    };

        alert(stats[0].Accountid);
    }
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to clarify what line throws this error and include the error verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's AccountId, not Accountid (case sensitive). JavaScript is case sensitive, so you must always use the exact capitalization of the field.

Comment: @SantanuBoral If you're using a merge field, like `{!Contact.accountid}`, then yes, the parts between the `{!` and the `}` are not case sensitive. But doing it from a query via sforce.connection, it is indeed case sensitive.